# Scoping graphql results with hapijs pre functionality

Tags: mongoose, graphql, hapi.js, apollo-server

I am trying to do preprocessing to scope my apollo-server (graphql) resolver results based off the user's authentication (which is expressed in a token in my header). I am not sure of the best way to do this, and this is what I have so far:

```
// Graphql Options
const GraphqlOptions = {
                          schema: executableSchema,
                          debugging: true,
              ---->       pre: [{ method: preMongoose, assign: 'm1'}],
                          context: {
                              user: Mongoose.model('User'),
                              SomethingElse: Mongoose.model('SomethingElse')
                          }
                      };
```

In my preMongoose file

```
'use strict';

const preMongoose = (request, reply) => {

  // code to modify mongoose model's pre to only return results based off
  // request's auth token

};

module.exports = preMongoose;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. They give you the ability to intercept the request in the server.register's options. This is how I am doing it:

```
{
      register: graphqlHapi,
      options: {
      path: '/graphql',
      graphqlOptions: (request) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          // a function that passes the scoping info in the response
          getScopableData(request, (err, res) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }

              // add scoping data
              GraphqlOptions.context.scopingOptions = res;

              return resolve(GraphqlOptions);
            });
        });
      }
}
```

You will now be able to access this field in your context when writing the resolvers. I had to go in and modify the resolvers to query only things that fit my scope criteria.